# Detecting Stack Corruption in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, callstack

I'm in the process of upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 to 2012 and a problem that looks like stack corruption has appeared.

I have a class with some member functions:

```
class Foo {
    double m_d;
    void Fn_1();
    double Fn_2(double a, double b, double& c);
    ...
}

void Foo::Fn_1() {
    m_d = 1.5;
    double a(1), b(2), c, d;
    d = Fn_2(a, b, c);
}

double Foo::Fn_2(double a, double b, double& c) {
    double x = 0;
    c = m_d;
    return a + b + c;
}
```

I compile with no optimizations and run under the debugger. When I trace into Foo::Fn_2 from Foo::Fn_1, the this pointer becomes 0xcccccccc which indicates unitialized memory. In Foo::Fn_2, the variable m_d is junk because *this* is junk. When Foo::Fn_2 returns, Visual Studio throws up an error that says:

```
 Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'x' was corrupted.
```

I'm fairly certain that there's nothing actually wrong with the code where the error pops up. I'm thinking there's a buffer or stack problem earlier and this is just where the problem surfaces.

Have you seen anything like this? Any advice?

Comment: Can you post the usage of your class ? for example a simple main that uses it the same that is giving the error.

Comment: Problem is defintely happening earlier because there is nothing wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: @john My problem is tracking down where the real problem is. I've disassembled around the call to Fn_2 and watched all the function parameters get pushed onto the stack. I guess part of my confusion is figuring out where 'this' is. If I knew that, then maybe I could watch for something that is trashing it during the call to Fn_2. When execution returns to Fn_1, the 'this' pointer is back to its original value.

Comment: Don't bother disassembling, just delete gobs of code until you have a minimal example to post here. Chances are that you find the problem yourself doing that. BTW: Have you turned on warnings and actually read and understood them?

Comment: I'm starting to think this might not be a real problem. After some research, I found that 'this' is stored in register ecx. When I'm in the Fn_2() method, ecx has the correct address but my debugger says 'this' is 0xcccccccc. There's still most likely something wrong in my code, but I think this error is actually bogus.

Comment: did you find the solution? I am facing the similar problem in Ubuntu OS?

Comment: @Hitesh I don’t recall exactly where in my code this problem was but around that time I think I was having problems with ODR violations stemming from a build setup that was had some stale obj files that were being linked in. I was also being tripped up by a directory configuration that was commingling debug and release build files. In the end, wiping everything out and starting from a clean set of source code files probably fixed this problem, then cleaning up my build configuration would have fixed the underlying cause. Sorry I don’t remember anything specific.